# Any suggestions for the root cause of this error while running behave BDD tests

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave, selenium-hub

While trying to run some BDD *behave* Tests from my local mac machine I encountered the following error. Has anyone else experienced it and any suggestions to fix it.

```
HOOK-ERROR in before_all: KeyError: 'SELENIUM_HUB'
```

Comment: By "KeyError" I'm assuming you are accessing a hash map key that doesn't exist? It's hard to tell from your question. Can you post the code in the `before_all`?

Comment: @Greg Burghardt Yes. I found the fix by passing the keys as command line arguments along with my run commands like
`$ behave -D SELENIUM_HUB=local`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by passing the missing keys (user defined arguments in the form of -D Name=Value) at command line while running the behave tests as `$ behave -D SELENIUM_HUB=local`